# I can't receive all HTML content of a website using Java code

Tags: java, html

I use Java to receive HTML content of a website. But I cannot receive all of it's content. Sometimes, I receive content, which end with "...", and isn't the end of content. Can you tell me what is error. Below is my code:

```
public static String requestHtmlContent(String sUrl){
        URL url;
        URLConnection connection;
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            url = new URL( sUrl );
            connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:16.0.1) Gecko/20121011 Firefox/16.0.1");
            InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is )  );

            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null);  {
                line = reader.readLine();
                strBuilder.append(line +"\n");
            }
            reader.close();

            return strBuilder.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Without actually testing your code, I can say this `while` loop is definitely suspect :

```
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null);  {
    line = reader.readLine();
    strBuilder.append(line +"\n");
}
```

The while condition consumes a line from the reader, that never gets processed.

Comment: +1 nice catch. Also since `StringBuilder` is mainly used to avoid String concatenation `strBuilder.append(line +"\n")` should be rather `strBuilder.append(line).append('\n')`

Comment: @bowmoer : But I had getInputStream() before. Or can you give me a solution. Thanks.
Thank you, Pshemo.

Comment: just remove `line = reader.readLine();` from within the `while`, so the line read in the condition gets processed.

Comment: @bowmore : Thank you. I just finded the reason of my problem. That code is have to remove ";" in end of "while" line. But main reason of problem , "..." in the end of result , because I see string on debug tool, and debug only show a limit number character.